# Google Script Replace Image in gDraw File

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So I am trying to write a Google script that will create an image file from 3 different image files that are on google drive.  The method that I have decided to use was to create a template or a base gDraw file in Drive and then modify the file and export it as a jpeg.  So far I've been able to export my gDraw file as image using the code from this post [1)Is there a Google Appscript command that can convert a .gDraw to a .jpg? 2)Can a trigger be set to perform this conversion on .gdraw file edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600752/1is-there-a-google-appscript-command-that-can-convert-a-gdraw-to-a-jpg-2can) .

```
function gDrawTO_jpeg(){
  var gDrawFile = Drive.Files.get('1P2qYTyeI9RovsI_qwiMEtlBeTJw-exjckQeYLL_NA7w'); 
  var url = gDrawFile.exportLinks['image/jpeg'];
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
               }
   });
  var jpeg = response.getBlob();
  // save drawing as jpeg file to Drive, or do whatever you need to with the blob
  DriveApp.createFile(jpeg);
}
```

What I'm stuck on is trying to figure out how to replace the images in the gDraw file.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across API for Google Draw, which mean is wouldn't contactable by script for editing. However, just a month ago Google came out with the [Slide API](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/add-image) which you can remotely add images to. Don't know if this helps, the slide could then be embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the direction.  Here is where I've gotten by adapting some different code I have found.  I currently have a slide with one image that never changes and 2 shapes that represent where the other 2 images go.  I build a new copy of the slide and then call downloadPresentation(id)from this post [How to download Google Slides as images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662455/how-to-download-google-slides-as-images) to export the new slide as a PNG!

```
function slides_template() {


  var IMG_FILE = 'IMG_4096.JPG'      
  var TMPLFILE = 'Grid Template' 
  var SZIMG_FILE = 'onesize.jpeg'  


  SLIDES.setTokenService(function(){returnScriptApp.getOAuthToken()});


  Logger.log('** Copying template **');
  var DECK_ID = DriveApp.getFilesByName(TMPLFILE).next().makeCopy().getId();


  Logger.log('** Searching for files');
  var rsp = DriveApp.getFilesByName(IMG_FILE).next();
  var szrsp = DriveApp.getFilesByName(SZIMG_FILE).next();

  Logger.log(Utilities.formatString(' - Found image %s', rsp.getId()));

  var img_url = rsp.getDownloadUrl()+"&access_token="+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var szimg_url = szrsp.getDownloadUrl()+"&access_token="+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();


  Logger.log('Inserting Images');
var reqs = [    

  {"replaceAllShapesWithImage": {

  "imageUrl": img_url,
  "replaceMethod": "CENTER_CROP",
  "containsText": {
           "text": "Main_Image",
           "matchCase": "True",
               }
  },},

    {"replaceAllShapesWithImage": {

  "imageUrl": szimg_url,
  "replaceMethod": "CENTER_CROP",
  "containsText": {
           "text": "Size_Image",
           "matchCase": "True",
               }
  },},

  ];


  SLIDES.presentationsBatchUpdate(DECK_ID, {'requests': reqs});

  downloadPresentation(DECK_ID)

  Logger.log('DONE'); 
}
```