# gdoc to jpeg instead of gdraw to jpeg

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I need to convert google doc files into jpeg files and then save them in my google drive.

i have found code that fixes a similar problem [1)Is there a Google Appscript command that can convert a .gDraw to a .jpg? 2)Can a trigger be set to perform this conversion on .gdraw file edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600752/1is-there-a-google-appscript-command-that-can-convert-a-gdraw-to-a-jpg-2can) here but I am not sure how use a google doc file instead of a gDraw file

```
function gDrawTO_jpeg(){
  var gDrawFile = Drive.Files.get('your_draw_file_ID_here'); 
  var url = gDrawFile.exportLinks['image/jpeg'];
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });
  var jpeg = response.getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(jpeg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a temporary Sheets file, recreating the document content on that spreadsheet file then exporting the sheet to an image.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327686/get-range-of-google-spreadsheet-into-an-image-using-google-script/58336922#58336922) is how I did this for Sheets (not Docs). The process should be fairly similar.

You could also submit a [Feature Idea](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762) for this.